# An extend and import issue - Android

Tags: android, import, extends

Here is the deal : I need to extends two different classes in Android.
An example:
In MainActivity.class I need to extends first TabActivity to use the tabs and getTabHost(); and in the same class I need to extends for example ListActivity or something else...How can I do that? Maybe my question is a little stupid but...
Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `MainActivity` doesn't need to extend `TabActivity` and `ListActivity` at the same time.

Only `MainActivity` needs to extend `TabActivity` and you can use a different `Activity` which extends `ListActivity` as the content of one or more of the tabs.

Here is the really good official documentation which has an example of what I'm talking about : http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

Comment: I still can't understand what you are talking about.In that main class I create the tabs.The content of Tab1 is Colllection.class and in this class I have the main tabs from MainActivity and secondary tabs in Collection.class. And i want to add a listview in Collection.class above the secondary tabs but i can't figure it out how to code that

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to have the tabs on top, a ListView just beneath and then more tabs?

Comment: http://i304.photobucket.com/albums/nn170/damcrew/Capture-2.png

here is a link of a shortcut of my app...so i need to build a listviw instead of that button moto gp and everything else needs to stay the same. The bottom tabbar is the the main bar in MainActivity and the secondary bar is the one with recommecnded and etc.

Comment: Ok, then the answer of Rasel and me are still valid. The activity with the secondary tabs needs to include its content as a separate activity which can implements ListActivity. If you look at the Android documentation example that's how the ArtistsActivity, AlbumsActivity .. are included. And ArtistsActivity could have implemented a ListActivity.

Comment: Now I got the idea! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can extends either TabActivity or ListActivity in your main Activity.You can't extends two all together because java does not support multiple inheritence.After extending any one create the reference of another to use in your activity.